# Can I alias a git command to a user-defined function?

Tags: git

I can alias a git command to run an arbitrary (non-git) executable like this:

```
$ git config --global alias.foo '!run_foo.sh'
```

But this doesn't work with a user-defined function:

```
// .bash_profile
foo() { echo "bar"; }
git config --global alias.foo '!foo'
```

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile && git foo
error: cannot run foo: No such file or directory
fatal: while expanding alias 'foo': 'foo': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to alias a function rather than an executable?

Answer (score 2):

`!` runs `/bin/sh`, not `bash`. To use bash aliases/functions run `bash` explicitly:

```
git config --global alias.foo '!bash -c ". ~/.bash_profile && foo"'
```

Comment: I'm getting `bash: foo: command not found` with that.

Comment: @Sasgorilla `". ~/.bash_profile && foo"`. Perhaps `export -f foo` in `.bash_profile` can aslo help.

Answer (score 2):

As [phd answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67201132/1256452), when `sh` on your computer is not `bash`—some computers are set up so that running `sh` literally just runs `bash`<sup>1</sup>—you will need to make sure that any Git alias that escapes to the shell has `sh` run `bash` if you intend to make use of any bash-specific features, such as bash's aliases.  (Note that `sh` may have aliases and/or shell functions that are just as good as those in bash, but this also may depend on your computer's flavor of `sh`.  Some Linux setups use `dash` for instance, and there are true-POSIX `sh`-es, and even a few not-quite-POSIX `sh` implementations.)

But even having selected bash directly with `bash -c 'command'` or `bash -c "command"`, there are pitfalls here.  Bash is a *very* complicated little<sup>2</sup> shell.  It distinguishes between:

- interactive shells;
- login shells (which are interactive); and
- non-interactive shells.

A *login* shell invokes settings from `.profile` and `.bash_profile`.  This happens when you first log in to your account (or start up a fresh Terminal instance, on some systems).  Subsequent shells (within that window, if in a Terminal window or similar) are non-login shells and don't invoke these files.

All bash startups invoke things from `.bashrc`.  Interactive bash shells are detectable, and some recipes suggest that your `.bashrc` should skip setting up aliases and shell functions for non-interactive setups.  Sometimes this is a good idea since you don't necessarily want your own private stuff to leak into system scripts.  But because the shell run by Git, or by `bash -c`, is a non-interactive shell, if you want one of your aliases to work there, you'll have to have that alias *in* that shell.  That means it has to *get* in there somehow, typically by being defined in `.bashrc` (not `.bash_profile`, not `.profile`).

Bash does, however, also have the ability to *export* shell functions and aliases, via environment variables, to sub-bash invocations.  This has some pluses and some minuses: some programs, for instance, might choose to *clean out* the environment, removing the exported settings, and sometimes you might even want that to happen.  Sometimes you might not.  So, be aware of all of these things.

You can cut the Gordian knot here by simply not relying on any of this: write your code as an *executable program*, perhaps a bash *script*.  Then most of this stuff won't matter.  If you *name* this bash script `git-foobar`, and place it in your `$PATH`, you will be able to run:

```
git foobar
```

and it will invoke your script.  No alias is required at all.

---

<sup>1</sup>Bash has an sh-compatible mode, in which various bash features are disabled.  If your computer has `/bin/sh` linked to bash, it should invoke this compatible mode.  Not all setups do, so verify how *your* computer behaves before assuming that `/bin/sh` *doesn't* actually just do bash things right out of the box.  It's not *supposed* to, but it might.

<sup>2</sup>Not all that little, at this point, but then, few things are these days.  I remember when 64 kBytes of RAM was a luxury...